# Making a website but need E-commerce

Tags: web, e-commerce

I want to make a website for my friend who wants to sell clothing items. I can code a website with html, css and basic Javascript. I think this would be great for a portfolio piece. My only concern is I don't know enough programming to build a shopping cart or the checkout. Or any transaction for that matter. I can code forms but only the design of them. Can someone more experienced lend some advice on what I can do? Is there a way I can design my own website but use something else for the e-commerce part? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://www.foxycart.com But i would probably recommend using https://www.shopify.com and there is going to be no shortage of work helping businesses get on shopify. If you do decide to do your own solution check out https://stripe.com and http://www.authorize.net for the transaction processing.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

1. Develop the whole store yourself
2. Use a CMS/Plugin to achieve that (like woocommerce for wordpress)
3. Make your site simple plain html with links to PayPal or similar's

I think you are looking for the last option here. It doesn't come with a lot of options, but would help you sell products and manage prices/expenses/return/etc. in a trusted service. You can create pricing buttons inside paypal for business website, and place them with html on your website. When the person clicks the button, they would be redirected to paypal's website

### PayPal for Business

> Premier accounts include all the benefits of Personal accounts, as well as our special features. Business accounts allow you to do business under a company or group name, accept all payment types for low fees, and accept payment from customers without PayPal accounts.

You can find more information on how to proceed on [PayPal Developer Wiki](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/)

cheers :)